# How to modify App.js to show HTML Template

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started using React and started a new project by integrating a demo html admin template all over internet.

I tried to do similar but ended up showing the default react page. One thing I observed is that the page shows the login page with inputs button on load but as soon as the full page is loaded the default React page is displayed. I however feel there's something wrong I'm doing in App.js file.

Below is my index.html code in `public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="some">
    <meta name="author" content="example">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/vendors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/extensions/toastr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bypasser/assets/vendors/css/forms/icheck/icheck.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/extensions/sweetalert.css">
    <style>
      .swal-button { border-radius: 1.5rem !important; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/forms/toggle/switchery.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/extensions/unslider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/weather-icons/climacons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fonts/meteocons/style.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendors/css/charts/morris.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <!-- END VENDOR CSS-->
    <!-- BEGIN STACK CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/app.min.css">
    <!-- END STACK CSS-->
    <!-- BEGIN Page Level CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu-modern.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fonts/simple-line-icons/style.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/pages/users.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/pages/timeline.min.css">
    <!-- END Page Level CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/plugins/forms/switch.min.css">
    <!-- BEGIN Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css">
    <!-- END Custom CSS-->
    <!-- manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>MS - Finance | Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body class="blank-page">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="app-content content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="content-header row">
          </div>
          <div class="content-body">
              <section class="flexbox-container">
                  <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-10 box-shadow-2 p-0">
                          <div id="login-section" class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 m-0">
                              <div class="card-header border-0">
                                  <div class="card-title text-center">
                                      <!-- <div class="p-1"><i class="ft-layers"> StackMantle</i> -->
                                          <img img="img-responsive" height="30px" width="200px" src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
                                      <!-- </div> -->
                                  </div>
                                  <!-- <h6 class="card-subtitle line-on-side text-muted text-center font-small-3 pt-2"><span>Enter Credentials</span></h6> -->
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-content">
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <form class="form-horizontal form-simple">
                                          <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-0">
                                              <input required type="text" autofocus class="round form-control" id="login-username" placeholder="Username / Email-ID / Contact Number" required>
                                              <div class="form-control-position">
                                                  <i class="ft-user"></i>
                                              </div>
                                          </fieldset>
                                          <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
                                              <input required type="password" class="round form-control" id="login-password" placeholder="Login Password" required>
                                              <div class="form-control-position">
                                                  <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                                              </div>
                                          </fieldset>
                                          <div class="form-group row">
                                              <!-- <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-12 text-center text-md-left">
                                                  <fieldset>
                                                      <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" class="chk-remember">
                                                      <label for="remember-me"> Remember Me</label>
                                                  </fieldset>
                                              </div> -->
                                              <div style="margin-top: -15px;" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-12 text-right text-md-right">
                                                  <a id="swap-forgot" href="javascript:" class="card-link">Forgot Password?</a>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <button type="submit" id="login-button" class="round btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"><i class="ft-unlock"></i> &nbsp;Unlock My Panel</button>
                                      </form>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <a href="/" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary round">
                                            <i class="ft-eye"></i> &nbsp;Let's have a look
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="pass-section" class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 m-0">
                              <div class="card-header border-0">
                                  <div class="card-title text-center">
                                      <!-- <div class="p-1"><i class="ft-layers"> </i> -->
                                          <img img="img-responsive" height="30px" width="200px" src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
                                      <!-- </div> -->
                                  </div>
                                  <!-- <h6 class="card-subtitle line-on-side text-muted text-center font-small-3 pt-2"><span>Enter Credentials</span></h6> -->
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-content">
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <form class="form-horizontal form-simple">
                                          <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
                                              <input type="email" class="round form-control" id="reset-email" placeholder="Registered Email-ID" required>
                                              <div class="form-control-position">
                                                  <i class="ft-mail"></i>
                                              </div>
                                          </fieldset>
                                          <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-12 text-right text-md-right">
                                            <a id="swap-login" href="javascript:" class="card-link">I know My Password!</a>
                                        </div>
                                          <button type="submit" id="reset-button" class="round btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"><i class="ft-rotate-ccw"></i> Recover Password</button>
                                      </form>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <a href="/" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary round">
                                            <i class="ft-eye"></i> &nbsp;Let's have a Look at Blog
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/extensions/toastr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/forms/icheck/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/extensions/sweetalert.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.flash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/tables/buttons.print.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/scripts/tables/datatables/datatable-advanced.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/extensions/unslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/timeline/horizontal-timeline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/forms/toggle/bootstrap-checkbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendors/js/forms/toggle/switchery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/scripts/forms/switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JS -->
    <!-- BEGIN STACK JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/core/app-menu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/core/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END STACK JS-->
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/custom/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is my code of App.js in `src/App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <p>
      Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
    <a
      className="App-link"
      href="https://reactjs.org"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      Learn React
    </a>
  </header>
  </div>
  );
 }

export default App;
```

Below is my code of index.js in `src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

What should I modify to make it work?

Comment: I'm not really sure I got your question right but I believe you should make a [component](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#components) first that returns or render your html and then insert it inside `function App(){}`.

Comment: even for the default html page?

Comment: how and where are you rendering your `App()`? Maybe give a little bit more information bc i think the question isnt very clear.

Comment: @EmWai i've updated the question

Comment: i dont think it has to do with the html in your public folder. do you have an `index.js` like file on your `src/` folder? there's a chance the app component is being run there...

Comment: Yes i do have it

Comment: could you post it instead of your public html file?

Comment: Done, pls check

Comment: Aside: I imagine the hacker warning (`Please Don't Waste Your Time Performing Security Checks Here. You Can Do Lot of Things Like Googling, Youtubing, Blogging. Then Why Hacking?`) is a waste of time. If anything, that would encourage a hacker to think they have found a valuable target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app component is being rendered on this line in your `index.js` file:
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`
try commenting or removing the above line and see if it helps.
better yet, modify the App() component to your desired content and not directly modify the html file on your public folder.

Comment: for css and js files, check the path of the file.

Comment: it shows `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/vendors.min.css">` after compiling, while coding it was '`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/vendors.min.css">`

Comment: `%PUBLIC_URL%/` is the prefix for the public folder. so `%PUBLIC_URL%/css/vendors.min.css` is actually `public/css/vendors.min.css` see if you have your files on the right place

Comment: Worked like charm :) if you think the question was valid, kindly upvote it

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the `App` in the node with id `root`. While the page is loading, you see the login form but as soon as the javascript is loaded the content inside `root` is replaced with the react content. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I'm new to react, i was trying to display the admin login page instead of default react page. However was not able to display it, after commenting the line in index.js it worked bu the css and js are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain if i understood your problem correctly, but as far as i can see you have not imported the public/index.html file at all. 
Your index.js file imports the App.js and the result is simply the contents of the App.js file.
If this indeed is the question you are asking, you can require the HTML file into a variable, stringify it (for example using [this stringify package](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify)) and the use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop in div to show the strigified content.